# RegEx to find numbers sequence in string separated by space with predefined maximum length

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Sorry for the confusing title, I'll try to explain this with example. Currently we have this expression to find number sequence in a string
`\b((\d[ ]{0,1}){13,19})\b`
Now I'd like to modify it so it fulfills these rule
 - The length should be between 13 to 19 characters, excluding the whitespaces
 - Each number cluster must have minimum 3 digits

The expression should mark these as matched:

> 1234567890123
>   1234 5678 9012 345

Not match:

> 123456789012 3
>   123 12 123 1 23134

Current expression that I have will mark all of them as match.
[Example](https://regex101.com/r/NOtQIi/1)

Comment: Why do you thing regex is the best option here ?

Comment: why don't you just remove spaces and then check for numbers and length?

Comment: Is this something a regex can be even used for? The only solution in pure regex I can think of is list all possible combinations of digit clusters. What kind of source string you are matching? It would be better (and probably faster) to match all digit/whitespace clusters (with a maximum length) and then check them without using regex.

Comment: @Nino If the spaces are to be removed, then I won't be able to differentiate which cluster is valid (contains 3 or more characters) or not. Besides the given string will contain not only digits but also alphabets

Comment: @IllidanS4 the source string is from a word document so size is quite big and will contain all kind of characters. The earlier implementation is using Regex therefore if possible I'd like to try achieve this by updating the existing expression

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible using look-around.

The regex can be changed to the following:

```
\b(?<!\d )(?=(?:\d ?){13,19}(?! ?\d))(?:\d{3,} ?)+\b(?! ?\d)
```

This works by looking ahead to make sure the number is between 13 and 19 digits long. It then matches groups of 3 or more digits. It then uses negative look ahead after its found all groups of 3 to make sure there aren't any numbers left. If there are, we've found a group smaller than 3. This works on the examples you've provided.

- `\b` Makes sure that its the start of a "word".
- `(?<!\d )` Make sure there are no numbers behind.
- `(?=(?:\d ?){13,19}(?! ?\d))` Looks ahead to make sure the number is between 13 and 19 digits long

  - `(?:\d ?){13,19}` From original. `?:` added to make non-capturing
  - `(?! ?\d)` Negative look ahead: if there is still digits left after getting 19 digits, too big therefore discard current match
- `(?:\d{3,} ?)+` Match any number of clusters bigger than 3 (min 13, max 19 handled by first look ahead)
- `\b(?! ?\d)` Looks for the end of a cluster. If there are still numbers left after the end of the cluster, there must be a cluster that is too small.

[Test here](https://regex101.com/r/NOtQIi/4)

Comment: SchoolBoy, I upvoted your answer, but you can achieve the same thing with this regex as well right?    / ^(?=(\d ?){13,19})(?:\d{3,} ?)+\b$/

Comment: @JBone Yes, although that requires that the numbers always fall on one line and that the number is the only thing on the line. In this case, I assumed you could have multiple things on the same line including the number, hence the extra checks. I would remove the \b from the end since you're already checking for string end using the `$` anchor.

Comment: ha, I see your point now. thanks. Also yes I forgot to remove \b at the end. good catch.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @EkaT No problems!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following solution also based on lookarounds:

```
\b\d(?!\d?\b)(?: ?\d(?!(?<= \d)\d?\b)){12,18}\b
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cb%5Cd%28%3F!%5Cd%3F%5Cb%29%28%3F%3A%20%3F%5Cd%28%3F!%28%3F%3C%3D%20%5Cd%29%5Cd%3F%5Cb%29%29%7B12%2C18%7D%5Cb&i=this%20should%20be%20matched%0D%0A1234567890123%0D%0A1234%205678%209012%20345%0D%0A%0D%0Athis%20should%20be%20not%20matched%0D%0A123456789012%203%0D%0A123%2012%20123%201%2023134)

The main point is that we only match the next digit if it is not a part of a 1- or 2-digit group.

**Pattern explanation**

- `\b` - starting word boundary
- `\d(?!\d?\b)` - a digit that is not followed with 1 or 0 digits and then a trailing word boundary (that is, if it is `12` or `1` like group, it is failed)
- `(?: ?\d(?!(?<= \d)\d?\b)){12,18}` - 12 to 18 occurrences of:

  - `?` - 1 or 0 spaces
  - `\d(?!(?<= \d)\d?\b)` - any single digit that is not followed with 1 or 0 digits followed with a word boundary (thanks to the `(?!\d?\b)`), and if that 1 or 0 digits are preceded with space + 1 digit (`(?<= \d)` lookbehind does that)
- `\b` - a trailing word boundary.

NOTE that in case you want to match these strings in a non-numeric context (that means, if you do not want to allow any digits on the left and on the right) you might also consider adding `(?<!\d *)` at the front and `(?! *\d)` at the end of the pattern.

Note that to match any whitespace, you may replace a literal space with `\s` in the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use Linq, this will be way easier to maintain:

```
var myList = new List<string>
                    {
                    "1234567890123",
                    "1234 5678 9012 345",
                    "123456789012 3",
                    "123 12 123 1 23134"
                    };

foreach(var input in myList)
{
    var splitted = Regex.Split(input, @"\s+"); // Split on whitespace

    var length = splitted.Sum(x => x.Length); // Compute the total length
    var smallestGroupSize = splitted.Min(x => x.Length); // Compute the length of the smallest chunck
    Console.WriteLine($"Total lenght: {length}, smallest group size: {smallestGroupSize}");

    if (length < 13 || length > 19 || smallestGroupSize < 3)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Input '{input}' is incorrect{Environment.NewLine}");
        continue;
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"Input '{input}' is correct!{Environment.NewLine}");
}
```

which produces:

> Total lenght: 13, smallest group size: 13
>   Input '1234567890123' is correct!
>
> Total lenght: 15, smallest group size: 3
>   Input '1234 5678 9012 345' is correct!
>
> Total lenght: 13, smallest group size: 1
>   Input '123456789012 3' is incorrect
>
> Total lenght: 14, smallest group size: 1
>   Input '123 12 123 1 23134' is incorrect